# Unable to connect to Postgres

Tags: database, perl, postgresql, cpan

I'm trying to connect to postgres db. Anyhow I'm doing something wrong as I'm getting this error:

```
invalid connection option "DBI:Pg:dbname"
```

Here the code snippet:

```
  my $dbinstance = "DBI:Pg:dbname=DB_NAME;host=111.222.111.2;port=1234";
  my $dbdriver = DBI->install_driver('Pg');
  if ( !$dbdriver ) {
      $dberror = "Load driver: " . $dbdriver->errstr;
  }

  $database = $dbdriver->connect(
        $dbinstance,
        $dbuser,
        $dbpassword,
        {
            RaiseError => 1,
            AutoCommit => 0
        }
    ) or die($dbdriver->errstr);
```

Any clue?

Thanks in advance!

Greetings.

Comment: Shouldn't it be all lowercase, like `dbi:Pg:dbname=`...?

Comment: I have tred both... Same error.

Comment: how is $dbdriver defined?

Comment: What's `DBI->trace()` output?

Comment: @fthiella `$dbdriver = DBI->install_driver('Pg');`

Comment: `$database = DBI->connect(...)` should work

Comment: @raina77ow `0 at postgres.pm line 129` (which is the line where i#m connecting.

Comment: @fthiella : indeed. 

Thank all of you  for your time.

Comment: In fact, there's no need to call `DBI->install_driver('Pg')`. DBI will load the driver based on the DSN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the following line:

```
$database = $dbdriver->connect(...)
```

with this:

```
$database = DBI->connect(...)
```